# Cocoa PDFKit add text to PDF

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, cgcontext, pdfkit

I am trying to add text to t a PDFPage. Specifically, I want to add it to the header/footer of the pdf document. I have looked everywhere for an example of doing this but I can't find it. If someone can point to a tutorial or give a quick example of how I can add text to PDFPage it would be really helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using [Quartz 2D - PDF Document Creation, Viewing, and Transforming](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf/dq_pdf.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH214-TPXREF101). This code will help you to write into file:

```
[someString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(100, 200) withFont:[NSFont systemFontOfSize:20.0f]];
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is to subclass PDFPage and override the drawing methods. There's a description [here](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/207723-pdfpage-creation-query.html).

Answer (score 0):

The answers here are incomplete, after putting various pieces together, here is complete sample code (Objective-C):

```
//  Need to create pdf Graphics context for Drawing text
    CGContextRef pdfContextRef = NULL;
    CFURLRef writeFileUrl = (CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:writeFilePath];
    
    if(writeFileUrl != NULL){
        pdfContextRef = CGPDFContextCreateWithURL(writeFileUrl, NULL, NULL);
    }
    
//  Start page in PDF context
    CGPDFContextBeginPage(pdfContextRef, NULL);
    
    NSGraphicsContext* pdfGraphicsContext = [NSGraphicsContext graphicsContextWithCGContext:pdfContextRef flipped:false];
    [NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];
    
//  Need to set the current graphics context
    [NSGraphicsContext setCurrentContext:pdfGraphicsContext];
    NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:26], NSFontAttributeName,[NSColor blackColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];
    NSAttributedString * currentText=[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Write Something" attributes: attributes];

//  [currentText drawInRect: CGRectMake(0, 300, 500, 100 )];
    [currentText drawAtPoint:NSMakePoint(100, 100)];
    
    [NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];

//  Close all the created pdf Contexts
    CGPDFContextEndPage(pdfContextRef);
    CGPDFContextClose(pdfContextRef);
```